# Typehinting array of generic types that return this array

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-generics

I have a method `useActions` that accepts an array of functions and returns an array of bound actions, basically like:

```
function useActions<A>(
  actions: Array<ActionCreator<A> | ActionCreatorWithoutPayload>
): Array<ActionCreator<A> | ActionCreatorWithoutPayload> {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return useMemo(() => {
    return actions.map((a) => bindActionCreators(a, dispatch))
  }, [actions, dispatch])
}
```

The usage is like this:

```
const [doFoo, doBar] = useActions([actions.doFoo, actions.doBar])
```

The problem now is, that doFoo and doBar expect the exact same type of parameters. I managed to fix this by writing additional overloading typehints:

```
function useActions<A extends ActionCreator<any>>(actions: [A]): [A]
function useActions<A extends ActionCreator<any>, B extends ActionCreator<any>>(actions: [A, B]): [A, B]
function useActions<A extends ActionCreator<any>, B extends ActionCreator<any>, C extends ActionCreator<any>>(
  actions: [A, B, C]
): [A, B, C]
```

But this feels cumbersome. Is there a generic approach to be able to support n arguments?

Comment: It's easier if you were to use named properties instead, ie. `const {doFoo, doBar} = useActions(actions)`.  Is that a dealbreaker?  I think it can be done with tuple mapping but I'm better at object mapping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using an Array

Binding an action creator doesn't change its signature at all.  It still takes a payload and returns an action.  That makes life easy because we don't need to map any types.  We just need to return the same tuple that was provided.  Instead of having the generic on `useActions` refer to a specific action type, we make it refer to the entire tuple.  Then we just return the same type.

```
function useActions<A extends Array<ActionCreator<any> | ActionCreatorWithoutPayload>>(
  actions: A
): A {
```

But now we have an error inside the body of the hook due to `actions.map`, since the typings for `array.map` don't respect that our array elements are of different types and will combine them all together.  We suppress this by adding `as A` after the `useMemo` call to refine the type back to what we know it should be.

```
function useActions<A extends Array<ActionCreator<any> | ActionCreatorWithoutPayload>>(
    actions: A
): A {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    return useMemo(() => {
        return actions.map((a) => bindActionCreators(a, dispatch))
    }, [actions, dispatch]) as A;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/zwOVrW)

### Using an Object

The `bindActionCreators` function can accept a keyed object of action creators, which is what you start out with anyways.  So why not just bind them all and take the ones we need?

We no longer need any `as` assertions with this approach because `bindActionCreators` returns the right type on its own.  We import the type `ActionCreatorsMapObject` from `redux` as the basis which our generic `A` will extend.

```
function useActions<A extends ActionCreatorsMapObject<any>>(
  actions: A
): A {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return useMemo(() => {
    return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
  }, [actions, dispatch]);
}
```

Your usage now becomes:

```
const { doFoo, doBar } = useActions(actions);
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/PmL0Am)